# Are there any LEGO movie/game posters?

Tags: shopping, accessories

I'm trying to find some posters for my childrens room and everytime I find something on EBay etc .. they are all A4 or A3 :(

I'm guessing it's a simple process as getting a nice quality version image and paying a Copy/Printing shop to print one in A2 or A1.

Does anyone know of any links to Lego movie posters that are in a quality that is acceptable for such a high print?

Or links to shops already selling em?

Sample images:

Clones Wars, Indiana Jones, Harry Potter, BatMan, LOTR.

As this is for personal use (sigh - I can't proove that unfortunatley :( ) that I shouldn't have any issues with copyright etc?

Appologies: for not having enough rep to create valid/accurate tags.

Answer (score 3):

If you subscribe to the [Lego Club](https://club.lego.com/en-us/join/magazinesubscription) (availability depends on your location) you will receive the official Lego Magazine and often a free poster is included. The March/April 2014 edition contained a reversible poster with the Lego City theme on one side and the Disney Princess theme on the other side.

Occasionally, you may receive promotional Lego posters with some purchases at the Lego Shops (or online shop). Brickset lists a few of these [here](http://brickset.com/sets?query=poster).

Bricklinks is place where you could purchase posters that are no more available from Lego. [Here is a list of all posters on Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/browseList.asp?itemType=G&catString=503).

Answer (score 2):

My son has a Lego Movie poster on his wall that he got in the "Mega" magazine a few weeks ago. I *think* it's A2 sized. We're in the UK though (I don't know where you're located) but I'd recommend looking at any magazines in shops to see what they include - some of them are a little expensive for what they are, but they usually bulk them out with free "toys" too.

In addition: Veynom has made a great suggestion, we subscribed my son to the Lego Club and he's had a few posters in the free magazines that come through the post (apologies that I can't upvote the post, I've just started in the Lego site and need 15 rep first).

Answer (score 1):

Besides posters, another thing you might consider is cloth display-banners. If you live close to a LEGO store or LEGO retailer who uses these, often all you have to do is ask for them when they go out of season. Here is an article featuring many of these beautiful banners. They are really pieces of art and they are large too: http://thebrickblogger.com/2013/09/lego-display-banners/